# Program runs fine in debugging mode, but running normally gives errors

Tags: python, selenium

This is my current code, but whenever I run it I get an error on the last line

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/OtcDownload"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

agree = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-warning']")[0]
agree.click()
nonats = driver.find_element_by_link_text('OTC (Non-ATS) Download')
nonats.click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/icon_download.png']").click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='checkbox-inline'])[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='checkbox-inline'])[1]").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/icon_download.png']")
print(button.is_displayed())
button.click()
```

When I run my code in debugging mode line by line, everything works fine without any errors. Any help would be great.

Edit: This is my stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\derpe\Desktop\python projects personal\testing finra\untitled1.py", line 31, in <module>
    button.click()

  File "C:\Users\derpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

  File "C:\Users\derpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "C:\Users\derpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "C:\Users\derpe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

Comment: Please provide the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox clicks are triggering a page refresh while you're searching for the download link.

Call `sleep` to allow the refresh to finish.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
import time   # add this 
time.sleep(1)   # add this
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/icon_download.png']")
print(button.is_displayed())
button.click()
```

I tried other selenium waits, but they did not work for me. Probably because the element search succeeds before the refresh starts but still clicks to late.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still a bit confused, doesnt implicitly_wait set a wait time for the command to finish? Shouldn't it accomplish the same thing as time.sleep? Sorry if my questions a bit dumb, I'm still a bit new to python and just started using selenium

Comment: I thought the same thing but based on the documentation, `implicitly_wait` only waits until the element is found. It does not stop for a given amount of time. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits